# Use a regex to get text from html source code

Tags: php, html, regex

I have got a php code that stores html source code of a site in a variable and I want to get two links from that source code only.
First link is in meta tag key content:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://img.xxx.xx/vid/xxx/b7950d611f934f0eef95c1cd010348e3.jpg"/>
```

And second

```
jw.load([{ file: 'http://vrbx105.xxx.xx/U7yvQnLiA_m5mhE9MUHf3w/1477628604/vl107aeb2d7db53f91fc6ad2e76fe11e49.mp4', provider: 'http' }]);
```

I need to get only those two links, they change every time a page is reloaded:

```
http://img.xxx.xx/vid/xxx/b7950d611f934f0eef95c1cd010348e3.jpg
http://vrbx105.xxx.xx/U7yvQnLiA_m5mhE9MUHf3w/1477628604/vl107aeb2d7db53f91fc6ad2e76fe11e49.mp4
```

Comment: You should use parsers, not regexs for this. For the HTML see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: Parser seems like overkill, never used it and seems harder than regex. The script I'm writing will be only for me so I need a simple method to do this. Only those links that I've posted above.

Comment: It is 2 lines with SimpleXML.. `$string = new SimpleXMLElement('<meta property="og:image" content="http://img.xxx.xx/vid/xxx/b7950d611f934f0eef95c1cd010348e3.jpg"/>');` then `echo $string['content'];`. Your regex is going to be making assumptions about whitespace usage, quote usage, attribute order etc.

Comment: Hmm ok yeah, but what I mean is, I'm getting whole site source ($page = file_get_contents('http://example.com');) which is a lot of html code. Now I need to get the value of content from meta property og:image, and the other one is Javascript code, so I don't think a parser would be able to get this. https://d3higte790sj35.cloudfront.net/images/md/xs/05f811fc99efc01a5fe93566ed8a0ff3.jpeg this is example of this code. Also the links change all the time

Comment: Yea, since you are getting a full website a regex is more likely to fail. Use a parser and you can have it drill down to the element/attribute you want.

Comment: Ok thanks I will work something out with the parser

Comment: You probably will want to look at http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php since it is HTML, not XML. Use the http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php, not loadXML (as the example has).

Comment: Ok I've got the meta og:image thing working. But I can't figure how to get that link from javascript code

Answer (score 0):

If you insist in regex, here's one for the first link: https://regex101.com/r/CHpfDY/1

And here's the second: https://regex101.com/r/VVF0Gf/1

Comment: Sure, I'm interested.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a [PHP JavaScript parser](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/jparser/index.html) handy, you can at least get rid of the regular expression for the HTML search. Something like this should work, though it's hard to test without the URL...

```
<?php
$dom=new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://example.com/example.html");
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);

$metanode = $xpath->query("//meta[@property='og:image']/@content");
if ($metanode->length) {
    $url1 = $metanode[0]->value;
}

$scriptnode = $xpath->query("//script");
foreach ($scriptnode as $script) {
    $array = explode("\n", $script->nodeValue);
    foreach ($array as $line) {
        if (preg_match("/jw.load... file: '(.*?)'/", $line, $matches)) {
            $url2 = $matches[1];
            break(2);
        }
    }
}

echo $url1;
echo $url2;
```